# install Composer on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, composer-php

> > php -r “if (hash_file(‘sha384’, ‘composer-setup.php’) === ‘e0012edf3e80b6978849f5eff0d4b4e4c79ff1609dd1e613307e16318854d24ae64f26d17af3ef0bf7cfb710ca74755a’) { echo ‘Installer verified’; } else { echo ‘Installer corrupt’; unlink(‘composer-setup.php’); } echo PHP_EOL;”
> > bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

> rafael@Rafael-VB:~$ php composer-setup.php
> Could not open input file: composer-setup.php
> rafael@Rafael-VB:~$ php -r "unlink ('composer-setup.php');"
> PHP Warning:  unlink(composer-setup.php): No such file or directory in Command line code on line 1

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you downloaded `composer-setup.php`:

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer -o composer-setup.php
```

Btw, full instructions from composer:

```
php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
php -r "if (hash_file('sha384', 'composer-setup.php') === '756890a4488ce9024fc62c56153228907f1545c228516cbf63f885e036d37e9a59d27d63f46af1d4d07ee0f76181c7d3') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"
php composer-setup.php
php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"
```